# Multiple where condition to get phone number from the client contact table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need your help in order to get phone number from client contact table which is in 1:n relationship with Client table and they join by client name

Here is the data from client contact table 
[image]

I would like to get following as result.

[image]

The problem is how to put the condtion.

I am getting what I want plus one row which is 1st row from client Peter Masae where PRIMARY=no , Phone Location = primary and PhoneLocationDD= primary.

please help.

I join this table to Client table on Name column and I need at least one number for each client and to get those first priority to get the number is where it says PRIMARY=yes and Phone location = Primary

But if record does't have that then look for 
PRIMARY=no and Phone location = Primary

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is what you want:

```
select cc.*
from (select cc.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name
                                order by (case when primary = 'Yes' then 1 else 2 end),
                                         (case when phonelocation = 'primary' then 1 else 2 end),
                                         (case when phonelocationdd = 'primary' then 1 else 2 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from clientcontact cc
     ) cc
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, Thanks for solution, it's perfect solution. Since I am using this as to get the phone from the client contact child table , we do have scenarios where client's name is in the child table but they have following scenarios where PRIMARY=null and no phone number no phone location etc , i mean the whole records is with null value except name or second scenario is just a one record in the child table with PRIMARY=no and and actual Phonenumber is null. How would I include at least basic information from Client Parent table where phone# will be null in both above case. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2040021 . . . New questions should be asked as questions, not in comments.  Include sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY PRIMARY DESC) NUMBER,
    *
    FROM CLIENT_CONTACT
) X
WHERE X.PHONE_LOCATION = 'PRIMARY' AND X.NUMBER  = 1
```